# IE 10 jquery click event of button not triggered after posting

Tags: jquery, angularjs, onclick

## uploadButton uploads an image and saves it locally. I use fileinput to select the image and uploadbutton posts the image data back to server.

It works fine on chrome but in ie 10 after submitting data to server the click event of uploadbutton wont tirgger. I have to click first outside the button element on the page then i can click on the button.
this is my code:

```
  <div id="fileInput">
    <span class="btn-custom btn-success-custom fileinput-button"><span><a>select file</a></span>
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" accept="image/*" />
    </span>
</div>

<div id="uploadButtonDiv" style="display: none;">
        <button id='uploadButton' class="btn btn-primary">Deel deze afbeelding</button>
 </div>
```

this is my script code:

```
angular.module('upload', []).controller("UploadController", function UploadController($scope, $http) {

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){

 $("#uploadButton").on('click', function () {
        
       alert('Upload image');
       
    });
```

}

I have seen simillar question but i have found no correct answer for my question.

Comment: Ahhh why is there jQuery within your Controller? Use directives, or `ng-click` !!

Comment: I am totally new with angular. if i use ng-click, the image data wont submitted to server.

Answer (score 0):

try giving your #uploadButton context

```
$("body").on('click', "#uploadButton", function () {

   alert('Upload image');

});
```

so there is an existing element on the page after the post to the server

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

Comment: I tried different ways of click event handeling but it does not help. The point is after submitting data, if i click some where on the page and then click on button it works!!!!

Comment: do you have an example file (codepen or jsfiddle) to better help you